# jQuery $.get is not a function

Tags: jquery

I got this error trying to execute a function `foo()` without setting an interval. Important thing is that my code is working perfectly if i remove this single execution and just leave an interval. Did anyone had this problem before?

```
var oldf = '';
var oldd = '';

function foo() {

  $.get("../Muxy/most_recent_follower.txt", function(my_old_follower) {
    oldf = my_old_follower
    console.log(oldf);
  }, 'text');

  $.get("../Muxy/most_recent_donator.txt", function(my_old_donator) {
    oldd = my_old_donator
    console.log(oldd);
  }, 'text');

  $('#followerid').html(oldf);
  $('#donatorid').html(oldd);

  console.log($('#followerid'));

}

foo(); // SINGLE EXECUTION BEFORE INTERVAL

var auto_refresh = setInterval(foo, 1500);
```

What I want to achieve is I want to make a single execution of this function at the start and then repeat it every 1,5sec. Didn't get an error when remove the single execution.

Comment: did you added jQuery library before script code?

Comment: @Bayrem my problem is quite the opposite

Comment: @AlivetoDie of course as I said the code is working if I just remove the single execution, so the problem lays here I think

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk Having the scripts in the wrong order would explain that. The interval function doesn't run until all the `<script>` tags are processed, so it will work even if jQuery is loaded after your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation for this is that you have your `<script>` tags in the wrong order. You need to put the `<script>` that loads jQuery *before* the one that contains the code in the question.

It works with the `setInterval` because that doesn't call `foo()` until after the DOM is completely loaded, so by then it will have loaded jQuery and `$.get` will be defined.

Comment: Totally correct, I forgot I implemented my script to more than one HTML and was debugging on the wrong HTML file.